# Python joblib performance

Tags: python, parallel-processing, joblib

I need to run an embarrassingly parallel for loop. After a quick search, I found package joblib for python. I did a simple test as posted on the package's website. 
Here is the test

```
from math import sqrt
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import multiprocessing 
%timeit [sqrt(i ** 2) for i in range(10)]
result: 3.89 µs ± 38.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
num_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
%timeit Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)(delayed(sqrt)(i ** 2) for i in range(10))
result: 600 ms ± 40 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

If I understand the results correctly, using the joblib does not only increase the speed but make in it slower? Did I miss something here, Thank you

Answer (score 4):

`Joblib` creates new processes to run the functions you want to execute in parallel. However, creating processes can take some time (around 500ms), especially now that joblib uses `spawn` to create new processes (and not `fork`).

Because the function you want to run in parallel is very fast to run, the result of `%timeit` here mostly shows the overhead of process creation. If you choose a function that runs during a time that is not negligible compared to the time required to start new processes, you will see some improvements in performance:

Here is a sample you can run to test this:

```
import time
import joblib
from joblib import Parallel, delayed


def f(x):
    time.sleep(1)
    return x


def bench_joblib(n_jobs):
    start_time = time.time()
    Parallel(n_jobs=n_jobs)(delayed(f)(x) for x in range(4))
    print('running 4 times f using n_jobs = {} : {:.2f}s'.format(
        n_jobs, time.time()-start_time))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    bench_joblib(1)
    bench_joblib(4)
```

I got, using python 3.7 and joblib 0.12.5

```
running 4 times f using n_jobs = 1 : 4.01s
running 4 times f using n_jobs = 4 : 1.34s
```

Comment: Is there a way to clump runs together so you can run 10,000 loops in one process, 10,000 in another parallel process, etc.?

Comment: tuning batch_size parameters you can send a bunch of tasks at a time